# sqlalchemy polymorphic many-to-many

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, polymorphism

I'm looking to have a list of objects belong to a parent class, in the following manner:

```
class A(object):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    collection = relationship(.....) # contains an ordered list of [B, C, B, B, C, C, C, B, C, C, ...];

class B(object):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class C(object):
    __tablename__ = 'c'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

The SQLAlchemy examples folder has a simple many-to-one where, in my example, classes B and C are "parent" classes of A (rather than the other way around), but I can't for the life of me work out how to reverse this into a one-to-many, and then add a bidirectional relationship so that it becomes many-to-many.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Are they (`class B` and `class C`) same or not?

Comment: No, they're different classes with different fields.

Comment: Then, What are the relations between `class A` and `class B` and between `class A` and `class C`?

Comment: In terms of abstract objects they represent different things; currently there's A and B have a many-to-many (as do A and C) but I believe this is irrelevant if I can work out how to create the ordered list `collection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a little painful and `AbstractConcreteBase` apparently needs a bit more polish, but it's like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, AbstractConcreteBase

Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class BC(AbstractConcreteBase, Base):
    pass

class B(BC):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "b",
        "concrete": True
    }

class C(BC):
    __tablename__ = 'c'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "c",
        "concrete": True
    }

configure_mappers()
A.collection = relationship(BC, primaryjoin=BC.a_id == A.id)

engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

sess = Session(engine)

sess.add_all([
    A(collection=[
        B(),
        C(),
        C()
    ]),
    A(collection=[
        B(),
        B()
    ])
])

sess.commit()

for a in sess.query(A):
    for bc in a.collection:
        print a, bc
```

Comment: Holy crap that's significantly cleaner than what I came up with -- eventually my solution used
```class BC(Base):
     __mapper_args__ = { 
        'polymorphic_on': type,
        'polymorphic_identity': 'bc',
        'with_polymorphic': '*' 
    }```

and then both B and C were forced to have a `bc_id` column.

Comment: Hey @zzzeek, I was wondering if there were any improvements on how this can be implemented.

PS: I love your work! Esp. SQLAlchemy and Alembic.

Comment: Also, I was wondering how this would look like if A and BC would be in a many-to-many relationship.