# Sqlalchemy: Querying on m2m relations for polymorphic classes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got two classes that are connected through a many-to-many relationship: `Parent` and `Tag`.

```
Base = declarative_base()

association_table = Table('associations', Base.metadata,
    Column('parent_id', Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id')),
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id')),
)

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('tag_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('parent_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=association_table, backref='parents')
```

If I want to query for all the `Tag` objects that have one or more relationships to a `Parent`, I'd do:

```
session.query(Tag).filter(Tag.parents.any()).all()
```

However, this `Parent` class is parent to child classes, `Alice` and `Bob`:

```
class Alice(Parent):
    __tablename__ = 'alices'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'alice'}
    alice_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id'), primary_key=True)

class Bob(Parent):
    __tablename__ = 'bobs'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'bob'}
    bob_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id'), primary_key=True)
```

Now I'd like to be able to retrieve all the `Tag` objects that have one or more relations to an `Alice` object. The previous query, `session.query(Tag).filter(Tag.parents.any()).all()`, would not do as it doesn't discriminate between `Alice` or `Bob` objects - it doesn't even know about their existence.

I've messed around with Query's for a while with no success so I assume that if it can be done, it must have something to do with some extra lines of code in the Table classes like those shown above. While the documentation holds info about [polymorphic classes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance) and [many-to-many relations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) and Mike Bayer himself offered someone [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622835/sqlalchemy-polymorphic-many-to-many) answer to a seemingly related question which looks interesting but which I'm far from understanding, I'm kind of stuck.

The code samples may disgust the Python interpreter, but does hopefully get my point across. Candy for those who can help me on my way!

Comment: I noticed you don't have a back relationship from Tag to Parent. If you had that relationship. Wouldn't you be able to access all the Parents of each tag. And then check each parent for relations to the Alice Object?

Comment: There is one, defined in the Parent class: `tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=association_table, backref='parents')`. I've done a certain relation checking like performing an extra `filter(Parent.id == Alice.alice_id)`, but this had zero effect on the final filtering (the bob-related tags were still there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing a little MWE I actually found a solution, which is actually almost the same as what I had tried already. budder gave me new hope for the approach though, thanks :)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey, Column, String, Integer, Sequence, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()

association_table = Table('associations', Base.metadata,
    Column('parent_id', Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id')),
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tags.id')),
)


class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('tag_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('parent_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=association_table, backref='parents')


class Alice(Parent):
    __tablename__ = 'alices'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'alice'}
    alice_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id'), primary_key=True)


class Bob(Parent):
    __tablename__ = 'bobs'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'bob'}
    bob_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id'), primary_key=True)


engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

tag_a = Tag(name='a')
tag_b = Tag(name='b')
tag_c = Tag(name='c')
session.add(tag_a)
session.add(tag_b)
session.add(tag_c)
session.commit()
session.add(Alice(tags=[tag_a]))
session.add(Bob(tags=[tag_b]))
session.commit()

for tag in session.query(Tag).\
        filter(Tag.parents.any(Parent.id == Alice.alice_id)).\
        all():
    print(tag.name)
```

If there's a good alternative approach, I'd still be interested. I can imagine sqlalchemy offering a more direct and elegant approach so that one could do, for example:

```
for tag in session.query(Tag).\
        filter(Tag.alices.any()).\
        all():
    print(tag.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write your object classes a certain way you can use the blunt force method...Just search for them...Kind of like a crude query method:

```
all_tag_objects = session.query(Tag).all()  ## All tag objects in your database
tags = []
for tag in all_tag_objects:
    for parent in tag.parents:
        if parent.alices != []:  ## If there are alice objects in the tag parents alice reltionship instance variable...Then we append the tag because it meets our criteria.
             flagged_tags.append(tag)
```

Sounds like you found a better way though, but I guess the ultimate test would be to actually do a speed test.

Comment: If your interested, I will post class tables to make this possible

Comment: This would work as well, but for a large quantity of Tags, I can only think that it would be slower. But if someone has the time to do a speed test, it would be nice to see how much :)