# bilaterally polymorphic many-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Sorry for the big words in the title, but I'm struggling with this

### Problem

In the timetable part of my database for an educational institute, there are Lessons (classes) and TestExams. Both claim resources at a given point in time in the form of students, teachers, rooms and maybe more. So my association table connects from either a TestExam or a Lesson to either a student, teacher, or a room (...). I feel like being sent in a lot of different directions by the documentation and various articles on SO, but none the wiser.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622835/sqlalchemy-polymorphic-many-to-many) article on SO seems to get me close, but not quite there.
[The documentation on polymorphic](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html?highlight=polymorphic#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.polymorphic_on) seems to indicate that it's not possible.

BTW, the classes are reflected from existing views in the database, because there's some more functionality in the data layer about change tracking.

The `Claim` table (my association table) has a `claimer_id` and a `claimer` type (== discriminator) relating to the Lesson or TestExam, as well as a `claimtype` (== discriminator) and a `claim` relating to the teacher, student, room..

For simplicity, I only present one instance of the polymorphism here.

Can anyone provide me with an example how to go about this? Or am I totally going in the wrong direction here?

```
class Lesson(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tx_lesson'
    pk = Column(Integer, FetchedValue())
    lesson_id = Column(Integer, FetchedValue(), primary_key=True)
    Lesson.claims = relationship('<claim?>', 
    primaryjoin="and_(Lesson.lesson_id == <claim?>.claimer_id,
                 <claim?>.claimertype == 'Lesson')",
                 back_populates='lessons', viewonly=True)

class Claim(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tx_claim'
    pk = Column(Integer, FetchedValue())
    claim_id = Column(Integer, FetchedValue(), primary_key=True)
    claimer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('<TestExam Or Lesson' _id))

    claim = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('<Teacher, Student or Room' _id))

class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tx_student'
    pk = Column(Integer, FetchedValue())
    student_id = Column(Integer, FetchedValue(), primary_key=True)
   __mapper_args__ = {'<Some Polymorphic black magic here>'}

class Teacher(Base):
    # similar columns ...
    pass
```

Comment: If you need `TestExam` or `Lesson` to occupy the same column `claimer_id`, they must derive from a common base class with a shared ID space, e.g. `Claimer`; similarly, if you need a `Teacher`, a `Student`, or a `Room` to occupy the same column `claim`, they must all drive from a common base class, e.g. `Resource`.

Comment: OK, I see the point there. However, this still leaves me with the problem of how to indicate the discriminator column on either end of the relationship. Or is there another way?

Comment: The descriminator goes on the base class.

Comment: Now I'm really lost. I'd think that the discriminator decides which table to relate to in the relationship from Claim to (Lesson or TestExam). I don't think I need a column in the Lesson table saying that this is the Lesson table, I need to know to which table the foreign key belongs in the Claim table, since the primary keys are not unique across the tables. Like this: SELECT * FROM Claim INNER JOIN Lesson ON Claim.claim = Lessen.Lesson_id AND Claim.Claimtype = 'Lesson'. I am clearly missing some crucial point, but what?

Comment: In a joined inheritance scenario, the discriminator decides what the object is. Take your example: a `Resource` needs to have a `type` column indicating what type of resource it is, i.e. `teacher`, `student`, or `room`. If your `Teacher`/`Student`/`Room` tables don't have the ID space, you cannot use inheritance to solve this problem. In your example, you are trying to make `Claim` polymorphic, which is not really the correct way to model this scenario.